# How to make a circular timer with Dates in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, timer

I need some help. I figured out how to make a Circular Timer, but instead of that, I want to make it with Dates, and my example is using Int values. For example, I'm trying to countdown from a Future Date ( Example : February 4 11:00 PM ) to Date ( February 4 9:00 PM ).

This is the code that I wrote :

```
import SwiftUI
 
let timer = Timer
    .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()

struct CircularTimer: View {
    @State var counter: Int = 0
    var countTo: Int = 120
    var nowDate = Date()
    var futureDate = Date.distantFuture
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 25)
                )
                 
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().trim(from:0, to: progress())
                            .stroke(
                                style: StrokeStyle(
                                    lineWidth: 25,
                                    lineCap: .round,
                                    lineJoin:.round
                                )
                            )
                            .foregroundColor(
                                (completed() ? Color.orange : Color.red)
                            ).animation(
                                .easeInOut(duration: 0.2)
                            )
                    )
            }
        }.onReceive(timer) { time in
            if (self.counter < self.countTo) {
                self.counter += 1
            }
                
        }
    }
    func completed() -> Bool {
        return progress() == 1
    }
     
    func progress() -> CGFloat {
        return (CGFloat(counter) / CGFloat(countTo))
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Date()` for all intents and purposes, is a `Double()` that starts counting every second from 1/1/70.  There are many examples of making clocks, and stop watches on the web. The one thing to be careful of is that your `Timer` is not guaranteed to publish exactly every second. Always rely on what the actual date is in your computations. Your future date is simply the current date plus a `TimeInterval`.

Comment: A `Date` counts from [00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780165-timeintervalsincereferencedate), not from the 1970 Unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a novice in SwiftUI programming, but I tried to rewrite your solution to get a desired output. All you need is to work with
**DateComponents** and then with **TimeInterval** as those two allow you to represent **Date()** variables in seconds, so you can easily use it for your timer. Here it is:

```
import SwiftUI
 
let timer = Timer
    .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()

struct CircularTimer: View {
    // MARK: Changed type to TIMEINTERVAL
    @State var counter: TimeInterval = 0
    
    // MARK: New DATE variables using DATECOMPONENTS
    @State var startDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 2, day: 4, hour: 11, minute: 00, second: 10)) ?? Date.now
    var endDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 2, day: 4, hour: 11, minute: 00, second: 00)) ?? Date.now
    
    // MARK: Calculated TIMEINTERVAL instead of original COUNTTO variable
    var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
        let end = endDate
        let start = startDate
        
        return start.timeIntervalSince(end)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                ZStack{
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 25)
                    )
                     
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().trim(from:0, to: progress())
                                .stroke(
                                    style: StrokeStyle(
                                        lineWidth: 25,
                                        lineCap: .round,
                                        lineJoin:.round
                                    )
                                )
                                .foregroundColor(
                                    (completed() ? Color.orange : Color.red)
                                ).animation(
                                    .easeInOut(duration: 0.2)
                                )
                        )
                    // MARK: Text view for DATE just to show you that timer is working
                    Text("\(startDate.formatted(date: .long, time: .standard))")
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .foregroundColor((timeInterval == 0) ? .orange : .black)
                }
            }
            // MARK: Changed logic for timer calculations
            .onReceive(timer) { time in
                if (timeInterval != 0) {
                    counter += 1
                    startDate -= 1
                }
            }
            
            // MARK: A few changes to the layout
            .navigationTitle("Timer")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Start again", action: startAgain)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Function for a START AGAIN button
    func startAgain() {
        counter = 0
        startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 2, day: 4, hour: 11, minute: 00, second: 10)) ?? Date.now
        return
    }
    
    func completed() -> Bool {
        return progress() == 1
    }
     
    func progress() -> CGFloat {
        return (CGFloat(counter) / CGFloat(timeInterval + counter))
    }
}
```