# How to countdown using a Circular Timer in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a little issue. I want to coundown using a Circular Timer. I made the timer, the formula is calculated correctly, but there is a issue. I want to countdown from a circle ( full orange ) to a grey circle when the estimated delivery time is matched. How can i do this ? I will share my code below, maybe someone can help .

```
let timer = Timer
    .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
@available(iOS 15, *)
struct CircularTimer: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    var orderDate : Date
    var orderDeliveryDate : Date
    @State var onTick: CGFloat = 1
    let date = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing : 0){
            Image("clock_button")
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.gray.opacity(22/100), lineWidth: 5)
                )
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().trim(from:0, to: onTick)
                            .stroke(
                                style: StrokeStyle(
                                    lineWidth: 5,
                                    lineCap: .round,
                                    lineJoin:.round
                                )
                            )
                            .foregroundColor(
                                (completed() ?  Color.orange: Color.orange)
                            ).animation(
                                .easeInOut(duration: 0.2)
                            )
                    )
                Image("indicator_ellipse")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 230, height: 230)
            }
        }.onReceive(timer) { time in
            progress(time: Int(time.timeIntervalSince1970))
        }
    }
    func completed() -> Bool {
        return onTick == 1
    }
    func progress(time: Int)  {
        
        
        let minutesOrderDeliveryDate = Int(orderDeliveryDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesOrderDate = Int(orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesCurrentDate = time
        
        let totalMinutes =  minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesOrderDate
        let remainingMinutes = minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesCurrentDate

        onTick =  CGFloat(remainingMinutes) / CGFloat(totalMinutes)  * 0.01
        print(onTick)
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991606/how-to-make-a-circular-timer-with-dates-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

```
let timer = Timer
    .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
@available(iOS 15, *)
struct CircularTimer: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @Namespace var namespace
    var orderDate : Date
    var orderDeliveryDate : Date
    @State var onTick: CGFloat = 1
    let date = Date()
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing : 0){
            Image("clock_button")
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "tick", in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.gray.opacity(22/100), lineWidth: 5)
                    )
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                
                if onTick > 1 {
                    Circle().trim(from:0, to: onTick)
                        .stroke(
                            style: StrokeStyle(
                                lineWidth: 5,
                                lineCap: .round,
                                lineJoin:.round
                            )
                        )
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "tick", in: namespace)
                        .foregroundColor(
                            (completed() ?  Color.orange: Color.orange)
                        )
                }
                Image("indicator_ellipse")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 230, height: 230)
            }
        }.onReceive(timer) { time in
            progress(time: Int(time.timeIntervalSince1970))
        }
    }
    func completed() -> Bool {
        return onTick == 1
    }
    func progress(time: Int)  {
        
        
        let minutesOrderDeliveryDate = Int(orderDeliveryDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesOrderDate = Int(orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesCurrentDate = time
        
        let totalMinutes =  minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesOrderDate
        let remainingMinutes = minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesCurrentDate
        
        onTick =  CGFloat(remainingMinutes) / CGFloat(totalMinutes)  * 0.01
        print(onTick)
    }
}
```